# Google Maps (left) click event fires, right click does not

Tags: javascript, google-maps

In my page [here](http://www.pdavis.nl/Amsterdam.htm), containing the code

```
 google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'rightclick', function() {alert("right click")});
 google.maps.event.addListener(layer, 'click', function() {alert("left click")});
```

in the body onload function, the (left) click event fires, but the right click event does not. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

'rightclick' event is available on map, not on FusionTablesLayer. 
you can see here events detail FusionTablesLayer:

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#FusionTablesMouseEvent